# Android device not scrolling my webpage

Tags: android

The webpage is not scrolling at all for android devices. iPhone and iPad work fine and on all desktop browsers it is fine.  Here is the css and link to site is http://www.fortmyerspressurewashing.com

Please help thanks::

Comment: You should post some of the code here as example to what you are doing.  Your link may not always exist and this Q&A is meant for many people to learn. (Not just fix my problem.)

Comment: absolutely want to learn!

Comment: You should create a minimal example which shows your issue as well (for that, you can try to remove parts and check each time if the problem disappeared); when you get a minimal example, post your code here. That's how you'll learn more and that will make your question appealing to answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the css file at http://www.fortmyerspressurewashing.com/css/style.css

go to line 15 and **remove**

```
overflow: hidden;
```